# Error while connecting to asp.net MSSQL database on godaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, shared-hosting

I bought a windows "ultimate shared hosting" from godaddy. I've uploaded all the files that are required,  the site works. When I created a database on myLittleAdmin and got the connection string from it. I put that connection string to my web.config file which is hosted on godaddy, but gives error whenever I send a query to the database from the hosted site. The string does works on localhost perfectly.

I just don't know where I did wrong.

---

This is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="GodaddyString" connectionString="Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog=db108;Integrated Security=False;User ID=USER;Password=PASS"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

This is the Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, 
please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="GodaddyString" connectionString="Data 
Source=IP;Initial Catalog=db108;Integrated 
Security=False;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
<trust level="Full" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" defaultLanguage="c#" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/home" mappedUrl="~/index.aspx" />
  <add url="~/ourstory" mappedUrl="~/ourstory.aspx" />
  <add url="~/anual_report" mappedUrl="~/anual_report.aspx" />
  <add url="~/education" mappedUrl="~/education.aspx" />
  <add url="~/error" mappedUrl="~/error.aspx" />
  <add url="~/healthcare" mappedUrl="~/healthcare.aspx" />
  <add url="~/livelihood" mappedUrl="~/livelihood.aspx" />
  <add url="~/joinus" mappedUrl="~/joinus.aspx" />
  <add url="~/mobile-library_stem-project" mappedUrl="~/mlstem.aspx" />
  <add url="~/mission-vision-values" mappedUrl="~/mvv.aspx" />
  <add url="~/our_partners" mappedUrl="~/partners.aspx" />
  <add url="~/the_team" mappedUrl="~/theteam.aspx" />
  <add url="~/our_trustees" mappedUrl="~/trustees.aspx" />
  <add url="~/whole_school_transformation" mappedUrl="~/wst.aspx" />
  <add url="~/contact-us" mappedUrl="~/contact.aspx" />
  <add url="~/volunteer_with_us" mappedUrl="~/volunteers.aspx" />
  <add url="~/ayang@news" mappedUrl="~/ayangsnews.aspx" />
  <add url="~/our-advisors" mappedUrl="~/advisors.aspx" />
  <add url="~/editprofile" mappedUrl="~/editprofile.aspx" />
  <add url="~/change-password" mappedUrl="~/chgpassword.aspx" />
  <add url="~/change-email" mappedUrl="~/chgemail.aspx" />
  <add url="~/edit-user" mappedUrl="~/edituser.aspx" />
  <add url="~/delete-user" mappedUrl="~/deluser.aspx" />
  <add url="~/register-user" mappedUrl="~/adduser.aspx" />
  <add url="~/gallery" mappedUrl="~/gallery.aspx" />
  <add url="~/Gallery/hummingbird-school-picture_viewer" mappedUrl="~/Gallery/gallerypart1.aspx" />
  <add url="~/Gallery/whole-school-transformation-picture_viewer" mappedUrl="~/Gallery/gallerypart2.aspx" />
  <add url="~/Gallery/library-program-picture_viewer" mappedUrl="~/Gallery/gallerypart3.aspx" />
  <add url="~/Gallery/video-album_player" mappedUrl="~/Gallery/gallerypartvideo.aspx" />
  <add url="~/ayang_manthan_fellowship" mappedUrl="~/manthanedufellow.aspx" />
  <add url="~/newsletter" mappedUrl="~/newsletter.aspx" />
  <add url="~/newsletterdel" mappedUrl="~/newsletterdel.aspx" />
  <add url="~/userdashboard" mappedUrl="~/userdashboard.aspx" />
  <add url="~/usereditprofile" mappedUrl="~/usereditprofile.aspx" />
  <add url="~/useremailedit" mappedUrl="~/useremailedit.aspx" />
  <add url="~/dashboard" mappedUrl="~/dashboard.aspx" />
  <add url="~/usereditpassword" mappedUrl="~/usereditpassword.aspx" />
  <add url="~/blogedit" mappedUrl="~/userblogedit.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
  </system.net>
      <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

---

This is the Error I get whenever I send a query from the hosted site:

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager) +907
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +334
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +699
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource 1
>   retry) +90
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource 1
>   retry) +443
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +120
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +160
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +108
>          Ayang_Final_Website.login.Login_button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jaevein\Desktop\website\Ayang Final
>   Website\Ayang Final Website\login.aspx.cs:39
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782698
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1639
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3394.0

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please delete your connection string details, server..., ID, Password etc. We never post such things publicly. Let that there isn't any firewall, someone could connect to your database...

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions for that error. Either the server IP is wrong or you have no access to that IP from wherever you're trying to connect. Unless the site and database are hosted by GoDaddy you won't be able to connect using an IP without the necessary networking configuration

Comment: The asp web pages which are uploaded on godaddy's httpdocs folder is sending the query to a remote sql server...  and I'm receiving this error.. What Should I Do?

Comment: But Using the same IP address, I'm being able to access the info from localhost

Comment: @Jaevein is the server up? Is you web server configured to connect to the database? There's no ambiguity about this error, and you'll find a *lot* of duplicate questions. As for why you *can't* connect, it's probably because that's an *external* IP that's not visible inside GoDaddy's network. Or their firewalls aren't configured to allow your web server to connect to the database. Or you forgot to enable that connection in the admin tool

Comment: That's apparently due to a firewall setting of your account. I don't have any experience on GoDaddy management so I can't give you to-the-point directions but there must be a way to add your SQL Server IP to some sort of whitelist. After doing this your application will work just fine.

Comment: @Jaevein right now you're asking as about GoDaddy's interface and configuration and the settings you used. The correct place to ask this is GoDaddy's support forums, although after googling for the error message I see they aren't very helpful

Comment: @Jaevein [this thread from 2010 may give you a hint](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?617123-RESOLVED-connection-issue-to-godaddy-sql-server). Depending on the choices you make when creating the database it's placed on different servers/networks.

Comment: @Jaevein does GoDaddy allow editing configuration settings *after* deployement? Do they have a dashboard for this?

Comment: @Jaevein check GoDaddy's [Connecting to a SQL Server Database Using ASP.NET 3.5](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwipivSznbviAhVMGpoKHSunDZQQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.godaddy.com%2Fhelp%2Fconnecting-to-a-sql-server-database-using-aspnet-35-689&usg=AOvVaw0Cc4YNUxUJpu2YkrIZbKC3). The connection string uses a DNS name, not an IP. Most likely the IP you used is only meant for external access. For *internal* access, hosters and data centers prefer to use DNS names, as it allows them to change servers simply by changing DNS entries

Answer (score 0):

This error often comes when your application is hosted on other server and Godaddy DB server down for moment.

Comment: this is more of a comment rather than an answer